# Is it possible to get and edit the display_name in another guild of a user in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to be able to get the display name of a user in another guild. To clarify the user will be in the same guild as the bot, however I want to get the user's display name in another guild that the bot is also in. I know this is a tongue twister so im sorry in advance!! But I just dont know how to do it???
The bit which says AFKGUILD is the ID of another guild, I want to get the users display_name in that guild! Please let me know if this is possible.

```
afkguildid = afktable[str(userid)]["guildid"]
name = message.author.afkguildid.display_name
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `discord.Guild` instance of said guild, and then the `discord.Member` instance of the user in that guild.

```py
afkguild = client.get_guild(afkguildid) # Get the Guild instance of the guild
mem = afkguild.get_member(message.author.id) # Get the Member instance in that guild

name = mem.display_name
```

Comment: thank you so much I think it is working! I am testing it now.

Comment: Nope it doesnt work> 'discord.client' has no attribute 'get_guild'

Comment: Could you update your question to show what you're doing now? Preferably with a bit more code provided than your original question, because this quite literally is the function you need. It's literally impossible to identify the issue off of this. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild